# If statement equal twice

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, return

I have an array which i want to search and check that if any value has more than one route. For example i want the computer to check the array and see if 0,1 comes up anywhere twice
which it doesnt, but mine seems to not work. I want this to work for all the values on the left. So no value in the first column should pair with more than 0 or 1 more than once.

e.g 0,1 and 0,1 should never exist twice and if it does the computer should return false but if it doesnt it returns true

```
    myArray=new int[][]{
        {0, 1},
        {0, 0},
        {1, 1},
        {1, 0},
        {2, 0},
        {2, 1},
        {3, 0},

    };



    for (int i = 0; i <= myArray.length; i++){

        for(int z = 1; z<= myArray.length; z++){
            if(myArray[i][1]== myArray[z][1] && myArray[i][0] == myArray[z][0]){

                check = false;
            }
            else{
                check = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return check;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with your "check", even if you find that there is "pair", in next iteration, it will be rewrite back to true.

If you want to know, if your array contains duplicity or not, it should be like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    for(int z = i+1; z< myArray.length; z++){
        if(myArray[i][1]== myArray[z][1] && myArray[i][0] == myArray[z][0]){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
}
```

Thanks to StephaneM, we found that you should change `z = 1` to `z = i+1`.

I also noticed that it would end in arrayoutofbounds exception, you have to change

`i <= myArray.length` to `i < myArray.length`

Comment: z should be initialized to i+1, not 1 otherwise the function will always return false (when i=1 and z=1 you'll check `myArray[1][1]== myArray[1][1] && myArray[1][0] == myArray[1][0]`

Answer (score 0):

Please check out (the control statement branching tutorial)[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html]. You simply need to break out of the loop when you encounter the first negative condition.

Alternatively, wrap this as a function, and in your nested loop just `return false` when a negative condition is encountered.